# How to change the content of list without affecting the (reference) address in python?

Tags: python, list

I am porting my C++ code to Python. In C++ I used the reference a lot to maintain some connection between a data source and the "pointer". In the beginning, I thought Python does not have the concept of pointer but after some research, I find that an assignment between two lists maintains the reference to the source list if deepcopy is not applied. In the following code, I am trying to create a list of some numpy arrays and have an external variable "pointing" to the list so any modification on the outside reference will change the inner data according.

```
import numpy as np
import copy

class myList:
    _data = None

    def __init__(self):
        self._data = [np.array([1,2,3,4,5]), np.array([7,8,2,3,1]), np.array([9,9,3,7,5])]

    def getData(self, reference=False):
        if reference:
            return self._data
        else:
            return copy.deepcopy(self._data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dt = myList()
    ref = dt.getData(reference=True)

    print(id(dt._data), '  ', id(ref))
    ref[1][3] = (k+1) * 11
    print(dt)
```

The above code shows that `dt._data` and `ref` share the same address, and any change made by `ref` will refect `dt._data` and vice verse. But if I need to reset the `dt._data` with some other source of data like

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dt = myList()
    ref = dt.getData(reference=True)
    newSrc = [np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), np.array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), np.array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3])]
    dt._data = copy.deepcopy(newSrc)  
    print(id(dt._data), '  ', id(ref)) # different address shown
```

The address of `dt._data` will change while `ref` will stay the same. After some trial and error, I find that performing the assignment row by row seems to fix the problem

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dt = myList()
    ref = dt.getData(reference=True)
    newSrc = [np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), np.array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), np.array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3])]
    for i in len(newSrc):
      dt._data[i] = copy.deepcopy(newSrc[i])

    print(id(dt._data), '  ', id(ref)) # sameaddress shown
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to solve the problem but at least if the dimension of the newSrc and dt._data are the same, it does not fire any issue. But if newSrc has more or less row than dt._data, will this cause problem? If yes, is it anyway like C/C++ to just change the content of a "pointer" (like *pointer = ...) but keep the address unchangedPython?

Comment: *Python doesn't have pointers*.

Comment: You should read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Thanks. It helps

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works as you expect, if I understood your question correctly. After modifying the value in `ref`, the array within the class is modified. Just change the last line of your code to see the difference as `print(dt._data)`.

In your code, when `reference=True`, the object `ref` has the same address as `dt._data`. Nevertheless, I would strongly recommend using always `dt._data` to avoid future problems. Why? Because if you initialize `dt._data` later on in your code, then `ref` will no longer point to its content.

When you set `reference=False`, then `ref` will contain a exact copy of the content of the array at that point of time. From then on, they will behave as completely different variables in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works but only when the list of arrays (i.e. dt._data is modified row by row, if the myList._dist is reassigend by dt._data = newSrc, it screws up the ref. I am not sure if that is a behavior Python design on purpose, that is what I am asking in the post :)

Comment: Sorry, then I didn't understand it properly. As @juanpa.arrivillaga shared in his resources, if you then reassign `myList._dist` your previous reference will be lost.

Comment: Oh, ok, now I understand it. Thanks.